# Laravel connec to database with user inputed username and password

Tags: database, laravel, database-schema

I'm trying to make some kind of a installer for a CMS I'm working on. 
The installer page is basically a page where the user inputs the database host, port, username, password and schema name. How could I use this inputed data to test if I actually can connect with the inputs given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user inputs into a controller function and update the `config/datadata.php`. Assuming the driver is `mysql` by default, you can do this:

```
public function checkDatabaseConnection(Request $request)
{
    //update the config
     config(['database.connections.mysql' => [
        'host'     => $request->host,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]]);

    //Check the credentials by calling PDO 
    try {
        DB::connection()->getPdo();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["connection" => "Could not connect to the database.  Please check your input."]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `use DB` at the top of your controller.

Comment: Thanks! Already got it working, but this is the same solution that I found myself, and it worked, so thanks anyways.